# Correction Needed for error in Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

I want calculate the all students credit hours separately group by stduents of each?
needed help to correction of query

[image]

```
select distinct altcode,name,
(
SELECT sum(CRHRS)
      FROM V_ALLSTUDATA 
      WHERE grades in ('A','A+','B','B+','C','C+','D','D+')
      group by altcode
    ) as completed_credit_hours,
    (select sum(crhrs)
      from V_ALLSTUDATA
       where grades is null
        group by altcode
    ) as registerd_credit_hours
from V_ALLSTUDATA
where sem_code like'%FALL-19%'
      group by altcode,name;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select distinct altcode,name,
(
SELECT sum(CRHRS)
      FROM V_ALLSTUDATA b
      WHERE grades in ('A','A+','B','B+','C','C+','D','D+') and a.name = b.name and a.altcode= b.altcode

    ) as completed_credit_hours,
    (select sum(crhrs)
      from V_ALLSTUDATA b
       where grades is null  and a.name = b.name and a.altcode= b.altcode

    ) as registerd_credit_hours
from V_ALLSTUDATA a
where sem_code like'%FALL-19%';
```

Comment: Thank you very much its working. Lots of thanks dear

Comment: now i want to calculate total of by sum up of completed_hours + Registered_hours by next column of registered_hours??/ how can do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `conditional aggregation` to simplify the query:

```
select altcode,name,
       sum(case when grades in ('A','A+','B','B+','C','C+','D','D+') then CRHRS end) as completed_credit_hours,
       sum(case when grades is null then crhrs end) as registerd_credit_hours
from V_ALLSTUDATA
where sem_code like'%FALL-19%'
      group by altcode,name;
```

Cheers!!